# Использование библиотек в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, library

У меня есть исходный код либы, я его собрал в двух вариантах(релиз и дебаг), после сборки двух вариантах генерятся сами либы и вспомогательный софт(графический софт чтобы проверить устройства подключенные) соответственно версии релиз  и дебаг тоже . После сборки библиотеки (cmake->make -jn -> make install) у меня в папках релиз и дебаг появились 3 файла: bin, lib, include. В директории bin папки релиз лежат файлы с такими же именами что и в директории bin в папке дебаг, у них только размеры разные(из за разных режимов сборок). У меня вопрос, почему дебажные либы не помечаются как в винде буквой "d" как в виндовс?

После сборки я добавил директории lib из папок релиз и дебаг в LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Когда начал проверять какие либы тянет софт( использовал lld), который лежит в папке бин, оказалось, что софт из директории bin папки релиз использует библиотеки, которые расположены в дебаге.
Как мне заставить использовать софт из директории  bin папки релиз библиотеки, которые находятся в директории lib той жей папки релиз?
(Либу которую я собираю intel realsense, JC: ubuntu 20.04, g++ 9.3)

И как мне вообще заставить софт которые собран под дебаг использовать дебажные либы, а не релизные.

Я хочу сделать так, как было в Windows на Visual Studio: когда пишешь код, то дебажная версия использует только либы версии дебаг, а релизная - релиз, соответственно при отладке использовалась дебажная версия бибилиотеки.

Я новичок в использовании linux, недавно начал активно пользоваться.

Comment: в линукс не используются виндовые соглашения о именовании файлов. Я бы строго не рекомендовал добавлять одновременно и релиз и дебаг каталоги в пути поиска. Скорее всего Ваш софт умеет работать с правильными библиотеками, просто попробуйте запустить в чистом окружении.

Comment: @KoVadim Но как раз я и проверил с помощью команды lld и увидел что релизная версия тянет дебажную либу. Что значит запустить в чистом окружении?

Comment: например, в виртуалке

Comment: @KoVadim получается что бы запустить нужную версию софта с нужной версией либы, необходимо в пафе указывать только путь к нужной версией либы?

Comment: крайне желательно. Но вообще то в линуксе принятно хранить либы в правильных каталогах /usr/lib, /usr/local/libs и тому подобное. Это обычно и делает install - копирует либы туда. Понятно, что в момент разработки это не очень хорошая идея и поэтому используют  LD_PRELOAD и LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @KoVadim да, я наткнулся на эту проблему. Когда собираю под релиз и по дефолту всё ставиться в /usr/local/bin , lib но потом я когда я собираю по дебаг и ставиться всё в те же папки, перетерая релизную версию.

Answer (score 1):

> добавил директории lib из папок релиз и дебаг в LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Потому и показывает те, что нашлись первыми ldd.

Обычно же линковщик ищет либы в папках `.`,`../lib/`,`/usr/lib`... и так далее - программа должна запуститься со своими либами без модификации LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Указать конкретно где искать библиотеки можно запустив

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../lib/ ./program
```

Comment: вообще во время разработки я пользуюсь дебажными либами, но когда я закончу то хочу использовать релизные либы посмотреть как будет всё работать. Как мне это можно сделать, можете подсказать?
Во время установки релизных и дебажных либ они все ставятся в одну и ту же дефолтную директорию /usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin , ..../include. Имена и релизных и дебажных одинаковые соответсвенно одни перетерают другие и поулчается что мы можем иметь только один вариант

Comment: для дебажных версий не делай install - запускай из папки сброрки.
релиз же можно установить